# c++ multiplication game branching statement issue

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, multiplication

So I am working on this math console based game. To work on the chapters of this book which I am reading.

I want to be able to make the game quit after using the no option.

**The Problem is that when using the no option the program will cycle through once and then quit. I want the program to quit immediately.**

I tried adding an else option but it keeps giving me the error code: "(26): error C2181: illegal else without matching if"

Also could anyone tell me how I could add the switch class to add more menus to the game. Would this require more function prototypes?

Thank you for all of your help stack overflow, I'm still learning how to use branching statements!

```
    // multiplicationgame.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void game();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char choice = 0;
    game();
    while(choice != 'n')
    {

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'y')
    cout << "\n\n";
    game();

    //else
    //cout << "later";
    //
    }


    return 0;
}

void game()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = rand() % 23;
    int b = rand() % 23;
    int c = (a * b);
    int d = 0;
    char choice = 0;

    cout <<"What does " << a << " * " << b << " equal?" << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "\n";

    while(d != c)
    {
        if(d != c)
        {
        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        cin >> d;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nCorrect! " << (a * b) << " is the answer!" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Play again (Y) or (N)?" << endl;

}
```

Comment: [`rand()` considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some braces.  Change this block…

```
if (choice == 'y')
cout << "\n\n";
game();
```

…to this…

```
if (choice == 'y')
{
    cout << "\n\n";
    game();
}
```

Also, it would probably be better to change this statement…

```
while(choice != 'n')
{
    …
}
```

…to this…

```
while(choice == 'y')
{
    …
}
```

This way, only `'y'` will be considered a confirmation.  If it is the other way, anything other than `'n'` will be considered a confirmation.